# Tomcat7 open index.html from directory

Tags: tomcat, redirect, jsf-2, directory, indexing

I have webapp in JSF2, something like
*mywebdomain.com/mywebsite/portal/index.xhtml*

Now I need to add an admin interface, I have created admin folder and this is working well
*mywebdomain.com/mywebsite/portal/admin/index.xhtml*

Users of this application will certainly not remember this URL, so **I want to create "shortcut"**

> http://mywebdomain.com/mywebsite/admin

In this folder is a plain index.html with

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/mywebsite/portal/admin/index.xhtml" />
```

**BUT...** when I type http://mywebdomain.com/mywebsite/admin, **Tomcat7 shows**
HTTP Status 404 - /mywebsite/admin/
...
description The requested resource (/mywebsite/admin/) is not available.

**So is there a way how to create this "shortcut"?**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `index.html` as a `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml`. This way the container will lookup for the given file whenever a directory is been requested instead of a file.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Alternatively, you can also just define `index.xhtml` as a welcome file, then you don't need the `index.html` file with the meta refresh tag workaround at all, the container will then just lookup the `index.xhtml` directly.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, now I have: <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>portal/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>. So should I just add to this web.xml index.xhtml as second welcome file?